Indicate whether a date is < 6 months before another date for the same ID column in SQL
I have something like this:
Id     Visit_Date        Visit_code      
A30     15May2004         Surgery            
A30     05FEB2005         Office             
B01     07DEC2002         Office             
B01     21NOV2002         Surgery           


And I need this, with a column indicating whether the person had a surgery within 6 months of their office visit
ID     Office_Visit    SX_past_6mo
A30        1              0
B01        1              1


I am trying things like this but having trouble with the sub query
proc sql;
select case when 
case when
visit_type="Office" then 1 else 0 end as office_visit,
case when 
visit_type="Office" and
DATEDIFF(MM, visit_date, select(visit_date where visit_type="Surgery") > 6 then 1 else 0 end as sx_past_6mo
group by Id


What cases are possible? Can multiple office visits and/or multiple other visits appear per Id? Does "within 6 months" mean between 6 months before or 6 months after or both options? I think you should explain more detailed your use cases.

Tell me 15May2004 isn't how you're actually storing dates?

This is a very common SAS date format. It is the formatted date as the user can see it, but it's stored as the number of days since Jan 1st 1960 in the background. It's not physically stored as a string. You can change the date format to a large number of types without altering the fact that it's still stored as a number. Giving users dates like this makes it really easy to automatically read in and convert it to a date.

You need to join the table to itself.  This code gives you each Surgery and the (First Office Visit After that Surgery), and (First Office Visit Months After that Surgery).  I am not sure if you wanted the office visit before or after the surgery, but I went with after.
select pas.Id as ID, pas.Visit_Date as SurgeryDate, Min(pao.Visit_Date) as FirstOfficeDateAfterSurgery, DATEDIFF(MM, pas.Visit_Date,Min(pao.Visit_Date)) as FirstOfficeMonthsAfterSurgery,
case 
    when isnull(Min(pao.Visit_Date),'01/01/1900') = '01/01/1900' then 0 
    when DATEDIFF(MM, pas.Visit_Date,Min(pao.Visit_Date)) <= 6 then 1 
    else 0 end as SX_past_6mo

from PatientActivity pas
left join PatientActivity pao 
    on pas.Id = pao.Id 
        and pao.Visit_code = 'Office' 
        and pao.Visit_Date > pas.Visit_Date
where pas.Visit_code = 'Surgery'
group by pas.Id, pas.Visit_Date


Based on the sample data you can summarize it this way:
select Id,
    max(case when visit_type = 'Office' then 1 else 0 end) as Office_Visit,
    case months_between(
             max(case when visit_type = 'Surgery' then visit_date end),
             max(case when visit_type = 'Office'  then visit_date end)
         ) between 0 and 6 then 1 else 0 end as SX_past_6mo
from T
group by Id;

In the real world there would be many other combinations of patient encounters. It might be more robust to use a subquery:
select Id,
    1 as Office_Visit,
    case when exists (
        select 1 from T t2
        where t2.Id = t.Id and t2.visit_type = 'Surgery'
            and t2.visit_date < t1.visit_date
            and months_between(t2.visit_date, t1.visit_date) < 6
    ) then 1 else 0 end as SX_past_6mo
from T t
where visit_type = 'Office'

